# Linq (MIN && MAX)

Tags: linq

What is equal of below sql in LINQ

```
select MIN(finishTimestamp) AS FromDate, MAX(finishTimeStamp) AS ToDate From Transactions
```

??

```
from t in Transactions
select new {
          FromDate = ?,
          ToDate = ?
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: You should have a look at the @CMS answer that is more interesting.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just do

```
var transactionDates = from t in Transactions 
                       select t.FinishTimeStamp;

var dates = new { 
                   FromDate = transactionDates.Min(), 
                   ToDate = transactionDates.Max() 
                };
```

Answer (score 39):

To use multiple aggregates in Linq to SQL, on a table, **without grouping**, the only way I've found to avoid doing multiple queries, is to make a "*fake group*":

```
 var q = from tr in dataContext.Transactions
         group tr by 1 into g // Notice here, grouping by a constant value
         select new
         {
           FromDate = g.Min(t => t.InvoiceDate),
           ToDate = g.Max(t => t.InvoiceDate)
         };
```

Kinda hacky, but the generated SQL is clean, and by doing so, you make only one query to the database.

Comment: just to let you know: "group by 1" does not work with NHibernate 3.2

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the aggregate functions if you want (Example in VB)

```
 Dim max = Aggregate tMax In Transactions Select tMax Into Max()
```