# How to write c# query to find the maximum and minimum value in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

how to write the below queries in c# to find maximum and minimum values

```
db.col.find().sort({val: 1}).limit(1); //min
db.col.find().sort({val: -1}).limit(1); //max
```

this is the query which I tried

```
var cursor = collection.FindAs<BsonDocument> 
    (Query.Null).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id"‌​)).SetLimit(1)
    .SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id"));
```

Please help me to proceed.

Comment: Do you use an ORM? Please post more info.

Comment: @Cristian Chereches: yes I'am using ORM. this is the query which I tried    `var cursor = collection.FindAs<BsonDocument>(Query.Null).SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("_id")).SetLimit(1).SetFields(Fields.Exclude("_id"));`  to find maximum value but not getting result

Comment: If you have all the entities in a collection (something like IEnumerable) then you can use collection.Min(item => item.PropertyUsedToCompare) and the same for Max.

This might also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107868/linq-min-max

Answer (score 2):

You could find the min and max document this way:

```
var min = collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("val")).SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
var max = collection.FindAll().SetSortOrder(SortBy.Descending("val")).SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();
```

Assuming your collection is of type MongoCollection<T>, then your min and max variables are documents of type <T>.

This is what's going on internally:

1. FindAll returns a MongoCursor<T>
2. SetSortOrder modifies the cursor by setting a sort order
3. SetLimit modifies the cursor by setting a limit
4. FirstOrDefault (a standard .NET LINQ method) enumerates over the cursor and returns the one and only document

Answer (score 1):

```
var sort =  Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("columnName"); //build sort object   
var result = db.Find().Sort(sort).FirstOrDefault(); //apply it to collection
```