# How to simplify my code? (Searching for minimum and maximum coordinates in list of lines)

Tags: c#, simplify

I have code that is searching for minimum and maximum values in list of lines. I need this to find center of rectangle that is bounding my complicated drawing.

My part of code looks like this:

```
if (line.X1 < Min.X) Min.X = line.X1;
if (line.Y1 < Min.Y) Min.Y = line.Y1;
if (line.X2 < Min.X) Min.X = line.X2;
if (line.Y2 < Min.Y) Min.Y = line.Y2;
```

I dont like this ugly copy-paste code. How can I simplify this/make it more elegant?

Comment: You could use LINQ. Have you tried that? Perhaps, something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107868/linq-min-max

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use an array? If you use an array you could use linq to query it

Comment: Side note: I don't think min/max will help you with "center" (also it depends on your definition of center...).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I need center of rectangle that is bounding my shape/drawing. Sorry for bad description / i fixed it.

Comment: @DanDrews I just don't like arrays, collections are so easy to use and manipulate...

Comment: Sure, min/max is indeed fine in this case.

Comment: "collections are so easy to use and manipulate" - you did not show collections in the post... I believe @DanDrews used "array" in sense of "any collection type instead of explicit X1, X2, X3,... x999", not just `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following populated variable:

```
List<Line> lines;
```

Get the X values and Y values:

```
var xValues = lines.SelectMany(line => new[] { line.X1, line.X2 });
var yValues = lines.SelectMany(line => new[] { line.Y1, line.Y2 });
```

Then get the minimum and maximum of each:

```
var leastX = xValues.Min();
var greatestX = xValues.Max();
var leastY = yValues.Min();
var greatestY = yValues.Max();
```

Note that this code isn't tested.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

```
var xList = {line.X1, line.X2, ...};
var yList = {line.Y1, line.Y2, ...};

Min.X = xList.Min();
Min.Y = yList.Min();
```

Comment: Thats good answer and good suggestion, but I had to accept answer with more details and some description.

Answer (score 1):

Here is yet another option just using [Math.Min](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.min%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Min.X = Math.Min(line.X2, Math.Min(line.X1, Min.X));
Min.Y = Math.Min(line.Y2, Math.Min(line.Y1, Min.Y));
```

Answer (score 1):

The design of your classes already has some duplication; your `Line` class's definition of a `Point` is duplicated in `X1`, `X2`, etc.

If your design looks something like this:

```
class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}

class Line
{
    public Point Start { get; set; }
    public Point End { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Point> Endpoints
    {
        get
        {
            return new[] { Start, End };
        }
    }
}
```

You could implement your calculation like this:

```
class ExtremetiesDeterminer
{
    private IEnumerable<Point> endpoints;

    public Line DetermineBoundaries(IEnumerable<Line> complicatedShapeLines)
    {
        endpoints = complicatedShapeLines.SelectMany(line => line.Endpoints);

        return new Line
        {
            Start = FindExtremety(Enumerable.Min),
            End = FindExtremety(Enumerable.Max)
        };
    }

    private Point FindExtremety(
        SingleAxisExtremetyDeterminer findSingleAxisExtremety)
    {
        return new Point
        {
            X = findSingleAxisExtremety(endpoints, point => point.X),
            Y = findSingleAxisExtremety(endpoints, point => point.Y)
        };
    }

    public delegate int SingleAxisExtremetyDeterminer(
        IEnumerable<Point> points, Func<Point, int> getCoordinate);
}
```

Note that this reduces the duplication. You would probably want to adjust this depending on how this interacts with the rest of your code.